# Node.js Pino logging - multistream vs transport

Tags: node.js, express, logging, koa, pinojs

I'm using Pino for logging in a Node app. I have read the documentation a few times, and it's still not clear. It would seem that Pino's multistream API accomplishes virtually the same thing as their new transport API.

I see that the Transport API leverages worker threads and writes async. Is this behavior consistent between the two? If not, what is the use case for multistream?